# How to distribute my graph app to other tenants?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-bot-service

I've made an application (using application permissions) that uses azure bot and graph API. The application allows the user to send and receive messages from teams to other applications. Currently, it's working fine but now I would like to share it with other people. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "share with other people"?

Comment: Just like a slack bot. I want to distribute my application to other tenants/companies.

Answer (score 0):

You distribute your app on a storefront or other method for people to install and use.

[Distribute your Microsoft Teams app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-publish-overview)